# How do I solve a "Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException" when trying to post to server?

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to POST a request from an android app to a server using http and json.
I have Wifi and I can access files and directorys on the remote computor.
I always get the "Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException" at the httpClient.execute(request);.
How can I solve this problem?

LogCat

05-06 16:36:17.871: I/System.out(12160): : 1

05-06 16:36:17.987: I/System.out(12160): : 3

05-06 16:36:18.171: I/System.out(12160): : OK

05-06 16:36:18.266: I/System.out(12160): [socket][0] connection /192.168.2.6:8736;LocalPort=40941(0)

05-06 16:36:18.267: I/System.out(12160): [CDS]connect[/192.168.2.6:8736] tm:90

05-06 16:36:18.268: E/Posix(12160): [CDS]Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException, functionName: connect; errno: Operation now in progress

05-06 16:36:18.292: I/System.out(12160): [socket][/192.168.2.214:40941] connected

05-06 16:36:18.292: I/System.out(12160): [CDS]rx timeout:0

05-06 16:36:18.303: I/System.out(12160): >doSendRequest

05-06 16:36:18.307: I/System.out(12160):

05-06 16:36:19.024: I/SurfaceTextureClient(12160): [0x51659430] frames:4, duration:1.307000, fps:3.059500

05-06 16:36:20.030: I/SurfaceTextureClient(12160): [0x51659430] frames:2, duration:1.005000, fps:1.988703

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

// Task starts executing.
String url = urls[0];
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.6:8736/AServerApp/V1/Stamp7");

String str = "details={\"DeviceName\":\"ATimekeeper\",\"BarCode\":\"13\"}";                     

StringEntity params = null;

try {
    params = new StringEntity(str);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

request.setEntity(params);
HttpResponse response = null;

try {
    response = httpClient.execute(request);             // <--  E/Posix(345): [CDS]Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException, functionName: connect; errno: Operation now in progress


} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The Manifestfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ancon_timekeeper"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.a_timekeeper.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />            
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```